# react native absolute position being cut off by further elements

Tags: css, react-native, css-position

I have a two dimensional array that I'm turning into a grid of squares. some squares should have an overlay, like a circular shadow that has an absolute position. It should extend over all its bordering squares.

Issue I'm having now is that the later rows (and squares in these rows) cut off the overlay and no matter what combo of zIndex or position I add to it doesn't change that.

Here's my code:

```
<View>
      <View style={styles.boardContainer}>
        {board.map((row, i) => {
          return (
            <View key={i} style={styles.row}>
              {row.map((square, j) => {
                return allowedSquares.includes(getCoordinatesString(i, j)) ? (
                  <TouchableHighlight
                    underlayColor={Colors.squareAllowedPressed}
                    key={j}
                    onPress={() => {
                      if (!square) {
                        setBoard(updateBoard(board, count + 1, i, j));
                        setCount(count + 1);
                        setAllowedSquares(
                          getAllowedSquares(board, i, j, dimension)
                        );
                      }
                    }}
                    style={[
                      styles.square,
                      !square ? styles.allowedSquare : styles.filledSquare,
                    ]}
                  >
                    <View
                      style={[
                        {
                          borderRadius:
                            Math.round(
                              Dimensions.get("window").width +
                                Dimensions.get("window").height
                            ) / 2,
                        },
                        styles.allowedSquareOverlay,
                      ]}
                    ></View>
                  </TouchableHighlight>
                ) : !square ? (
                  <View
                    key={j}
                    style={[
                      styles.square,
                    ]}
                  ></View>
                ) : square === count.toString() ? (
                  <View
                    key={j}
                    style={[
                      styles.square,
                      styles.currentSquare,
                    ]}
                  >
                    <Text style={styles.squareText}>{square}</Text>
                  </View>
                ) : (
                  <View
                    key={j}
                    style={[
                      styles.square,
                      styles.filledSquare,
                    ]}
                  >
                    <Text style={styles.squareText}>{square}</Text>
                  </View>
                );
              })}
            </View>
          );
        })}
      </View>
    </View>
```

Styles:

```
const getStyles = (dimension: number) => {
  return StyleSheet.create({
    boardContainer: {
      display: "flex",
      flexDirection: "column",
      width: "100%",
      borderTopWidth: 0,
      borderBottomWidth: 0,
      borderColor: Colors.squareBorderColor,
      backgroundColor: Colors.gameOverBgColor,
      paddingVertical: 30,
    },
    row: {
      flexDirection: "row",
      width: "100%",
    },
    square: {
      flex: 1,
      display: "flex",
      justifyContent: "center",
      alignItems: "center",
      //   borderTopWidth: 2,
      //   borderBottomWidth: 2,
      borderColor: Colors.squareBorderColor,
      backgroundColor: Colors.boardBgColor,
      aspectRatio: 1,
      zIndex: 1,
    },
    noBorderLeft: {
      borderLeftWidth: 0,
    },

    borderLeft: {
      borderLeftWidth: 2,
    },
    noBorderRight: {
      borderRightWidth: 0,
    },
    borderRight: {
      borderRightWidth: 2,
    },
    filledSquare: {
      backgroundColor: Colors.squareFilled,
      color: Colors.squareTextColor,
    },
    allowedSquare: {
      backgroundColor: Colors.squareAllowed,
      zIndex: 2,
      position: "relative",
    },
    allowedSquareOverlay: {
      backgroundColor: "rgba(204, 103, 154, .3)",
      opacity: 1,
      width: "200%",
      height: "200%",
      position: "absolute",
      zIndex: 10,
    },
    squareText: {
      color: Colors.squareTextColor,
      fontSize: 150 / dimension,
      fontWeight: "700",
    },
    currentSquare: {
      backgroundColor: Colors.currentSquare,
      color: Colors.squareTextColor,
    },
  });
};
```

I don't really understand react-native's position since it doesn't act like standard css absolute position. I'm new to react-native and having trouble figuring this out.

EDIT: I've updated the code. As of now the overlay is cut off by the row/squares beneath it, as in the bottom row, the overlay extends over all squares.

I need a way to have the overlay's position be absolute and not be cut off. Current answer doesn't fix it.

Answer (score 2):

Each `.allowedSquare` is in its own new [stacking context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_positioned_layout/Understanding_z-index/Stacking_context) and as such the z-index of its child `.allowedSquareOverlay` is relative to its parent only.

#### A demo to illustrate the problem.

Note how the child 'overlays' are still behind their parent's next siblings.

```css
section {
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  gap:4px;
}

.allowedSquare {
    background-color: green;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    display:block;
    aspect-ratio: 1;
  }
  
.allowedSquareOverlay {
    background-color: red;
    opacity: 0.3;
    width: 175%;
    height: 175%;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
  }
```

```html
<section>
<div class="allowedSquare">1<div class="allowedSquareOverlay">a</div></div>
<div class="allowedSquare">2</div>
<div class="allowedSquare">3<div class="allowedSquareOverlay">c</div></div>
<div class="allowedSquare">4</div>
<div class="allowedSquare">5<div class="allowedSquareOverlay">e</div></div>
<div class="allowedSquare">6</div>
</section>
```

At the time of writing there is no 'global' z-index properties so you will need to remove the stacking context from the parents or decrement the z-index programatically.

#### A possible solution.

Remove the z-index from .allowedSquare (or set it to auto) to remove the stacking context:

```
allowedSquare: {
    backgroundColor: Colors.squareAllowed,
    position: "relative",
    zIndex: "auto",
  }
```

See also: https://docs.expo.dev/ui-programming/z-index/

Demo:

```css
section {
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  gap:4px;
}

.allowedSquare {
    background-color: green;
    position: relative;
    display:block;
    aspect-ratio: 1;
    z-index: auto;
  }
  
.allowedSquareOverlay {
    background-color: red;
    opacity: 0.3;
    width: 175%;
    height: 175%;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
  }
```

```html
<section>
<div class="allowedSquare">1<div class="allowedSquareOverlay">a</div></div>
<div class="allowedSquare">2</div>
<div class="allowedSquare">3<div class="allowedSquareOverlay">c</div></div>
<div class="allowedSquare">4</div>
<div class="allowedSquare">5<div class="allowedSquareOverlay">e</div></div>
<div class="allowedSquare">6</div>
</section>
```

Comment: zIndex can only be a number. the issue is still present, square overlay is cutoff by next row/squares

Comment: Remove the zIndex entirely from allowedSquare?

Comment: still didn't work. overlay is getting cut off by other squares

Comment: In which case you will probably have to programmatically set the zIndex (or elevation) of each of your board squares as you create them. Clues here: https://docs.expo.dev/ui-programming/z-index/

Comment: all i need is to set the allowed squares and allowed squares overlay to have a higher elevation/zIndex then any other type of square but can't get it to work...

Comment: You need the zIndex to descend so that each square is above the next sibling. In your react-native code you should define a variable which you decrement on each loop. Use this variable inline in the View's style to force the zIndex you require. Something like: `View style={[styles.square, {zIndex: myCustomZIndex}]}>`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255019/discussion-between-yehuda-and-moob).